# How to efficiently populate a sharepoint online list with thousands of items?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Anyone able to suggest how to efficiently import tents of thousands test items in a sharepoint online list? I've tried using powershell but it proved to be very slow (not sure if due to SPO throttling).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use "Client Side Object Model" to import the large list in sharepoint online. Recently I did the same in my current Project.

Comment: Tried using CSOM and althought not super fast I was able to upload around 20K items per hour